# Building a Qt 4.8 application on Visual Studio

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, qt4

I'm working on building Open-Sankoré project (https://github.com/Sankore/Sankore-3.1) which is made by Qt 4.8-msvc compiler..

But, visual studio 2015 only works with Qt5 and doesn't accept Qt4 packages directly..

So my question is whether there's any walk-around that could be done to make visual studio build Qt 4.8 projects ?

Comment: My fork builds under Qt 5 and runs (yay!), but still requires phonon. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to compile Qt4.8 from source if you want to use Visual Studio 2015 with that exact version (4.8). There is [no official release of Qt4.8](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/supported-platforms.html) that was built using msvc2015.

If you are really tied to the Qt4.8 version, my suggestion would be to download and install lower version of Visual Studio and the corresponding compiler, e.g., msvc2008.

Although, before doing so, I would confirm if the project you are trying to build is really bounded to the Qt4.8 version. It might work as expected with the higher Qt version; or with [some added modifications](https://wiki.qt.io/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5).

Comment: If I take the path of making changes to be compatible to Qt5..The project depends on Phonon module(removed from qt5)..is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: In this case, it would require more work. See this page: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/portingguide.html and the commend about Phonon module and qt5 at the end. So, theoretically speaking, it is possible to do the porting but with some effort. The easiest part would, probably, be to download the lower version compiler to try to compile the program for the first time as it is.

Comment: You are right..I was able to build&run it using VS2008..Thnx vicrucann! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sankore is a bit of a mess and is abandonware, but I've forked it and ported it to Qt 5 and it was not a big job. The build system is still iffy and I haven't tested it on anything but OS X.

It currently builds and functions from a stand-alone top project under Qt Creator, i.e. the dependencies (other than Phonon) get built alongside the rest of it.

Phonon builds under Qt 5 - see [phonon4qt5](https://api.kde.org/kdesupport-api/phonon-apidocs/phonon/html/phonon4qt5.html). It needs cmake and may be a bit iffy. Only a few classes need phonon in Sankore, and thus require porting over to Qt Multimedia. That should be the first order of business if you wish to work on the code.

Check out the `qt5-compat` branch from these repositories:

https://github.com/KubaO/Sankore-3.1

https://github.com/KubaO/Sankore-ThirdParty

I'm accepting pull requests, of course.

Comment: Oooookay! I'll try it on windows and tell u..Thnx a lot man :D

Comment: I downloaded ur repos (branch qt5-compat) and opened Sankore_top.pro file using qtcreator (Qt 5.7.0 MinGW 32 bit kit) but several errors appeared to me like unknown modules: webkit phonon4qt5 webkitwidgets...
So, What exact version of Qt5 kit did u use on Qt creator?

Comment: There's a readme. You need to follow the steps there for OS X and adjust them for Windows. You need Qt 5.5.1, you need to build the webkit module so you need to build ICU before you build to Qt, and you need to build phonon too. It does require some work. Maybe later today it'll build without any extra dependencies. Remember that just a few days ago it built under no Qt 5 version at all :)